# Element <option> could not be scrolled into view C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select option from dropdown, but it returns the error: *OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view.*

Select form looks like this:

```
<div ...>
  <dd id="names-element">
    <select name="names", id="names", tabindex="-1", style="display: none">
      <option value="Ann">Ann</option>
      <option value="Jon">Jon</option>
      <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
      <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
    </select>
  </dd>
</div>
```

My code:

```
IWebElement namesElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("names"));
SelectElement namesSelect = new SelectElement(namesElement );
namesSelect.SelectByValue("Jon");
```

I've tried to use webwait likes:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(namesElement));
```

But at this point it returns:
*OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds*

Then i've tried to use javascript executor:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor je = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
je.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", namesElement);
```

But after that it returns again:
*OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view.*

I'm actually newbie in Selenium and prefer python, but at this time need to use C#. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: `style="display: none"` is why. It's not visible. You either have to do something on the page to make it visible or it may be for mobile when you are using desktop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Scroll to that element using javascript like :

```
IWebElement namesElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("names"));
driver.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", namesElement);
SelectElement namesSelect = new SelectElement(namesElement );
namesSelect.SelectByValue("Jon");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it has not been working. It raises again:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element could not be scrolled into view.
I think that it raises the error because display is none in style of select element.

Comment: Try getOptions() method on your namesSelect, If it is returning you the webelements then we are sure that element is getting identified. If not try to change your element identification using xpath like : //dd[@id='names-element']/select[@id='names']
then click on dropdown- namesElement.click(), then select the value using selectByValue().Also,see if there is any button near the dropdown? can you click the dropdown itself?If yes inspect if the display attribute changes. If it does change to "block" or something similar,need to click the dropdown element before finding the option.

Answer (score 0):

The `style="display: none"` means that the element is not visible on the webpage. 
Make sure that this is a unique identifier. Sometimes, there are multiple elements in the DOM with exact same identifier however, the only difference is `stype="dispay: block"`

Once you have made sure that the identifier is absolutely correct, you can then use `SelectElement` class to choose the element by value.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've solved the problem using div element located under  the select elements, clicked to names-element and then find span elements by xpath in div.